# AMPQ:- 'history'. Expected [class MessageHistory] but actual type is [class ArrayList]

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

Spring Integration and Spring Integration AMQP.

I have the following code:

```
<bean id="allHeadersMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper">
        <property name="requestHeaderNames" value="*" />
        <property name="replyHeaderNames" value="*" />
    </bean>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="ResponseChannel" queue-names="OutputQueue" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" error-channel="274ErrorChannel" header-mapper="allHeadersMapper"  />
```

I am converting the EDI message to JSON and Placing in "OutputQueue" . While I try to Read the mesage from OutputQueue and Place in Channel, I try to map all standard and non Standard Header.

Eg.

```
[payload={abcPayload}, headers={amqp_consumerQueue=OutputQueue, amqp_receivedExchange=XExchange, VERSION_ID=1.0, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentType=text/plain, amqp_redelivered=true, STATUS=ABC, timestamp=1432235031343, id=793599d5-6236-c6a1-717e-4f85f9cd9f7b, history=JSONChannel,ResponseLogging,FilterChannel1, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=OutputQueueKey, MESSAGE_ID=MESSAGE_ID, amqp_deliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, RECORD_ID=RECORD_ID, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-7jyApLDNT5s_HbxOU8gkPQ, FLOW_NAME=BCD, amqp_deliveryTag=1}]
```

I am getting the Exception:

```
Incorrect type specified for header 'history'. Expected [class org.springframework.integration.history.MessageHistory] but actual type is [class java.util.ArrayList]
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing more StackTrace to determine the guilty component.